# Handling Bad English

Tags: grammar

It might be an odd question but how to handle bad English  By handle I mean: understand it and correct it. Sometimes you meet phrases that are written in very bad English. Mostly the work of poor translators. When you read these articles you can't surely know if what you've understood is what is really written. You always have to guess. There are many examples on the web.

Comment: "God grant me the serenity to accept the things I cannot change; courage to change the things I can; and wisdom to know the difference." ~ Reinhold Niebuhr

Comment: @Mick it's not that bad

Comment: I regret that I must inform you (though you may find it consoling) that most very bad English is written not by poor translators but by incompetent native speakers.

Comment: @StoneyB this cannot be. Natives making mistakes and writing incorrectly? Oh, you mustabe kiddin'.

Comment: Is this a meta question or one about English as a whole?

Comment: Here is my own approach. If possible, ask the writer. If not, try to get the big picture, i.e., what they're trying to say, as a whole; chunk it out, i.e., understand each of their clumsy sentences chunk by chunk--this give you a better chance to understand an ambiguous sentence; finally, pay more attention to key words, and less to syntax and grammar. I hope this is a bit useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remember the person who writes poor English might be a literary genius in their native language.  Second languages can be hard, especially if you're not regularly exposed to native speakers.
2. There is always a logic behind every sentence, no matter how poorly formed.  If you are familiar with the quirks of a particular language, you can sometimes guess what the native speaker of that language is *trying* to say in English, just filtered through what is familiar to them.
3. English is a notoriously difficult language.  It has many common quirks that make no logical sense and which must be memorized.  It contradicts itself all over the place, and nuances vary widely from dialect to dialect.

Perhaps more than any other language, English speakers get used to non-native speakers trying to communicate in English and (hopefully) learn to "read between the lines" when something is unclear.  Of course there are many people who won't bother, but as someone who has been in the same situation in many other countries where I didn't speak the native language, I try to empathize with what anyone is trying to say.

Comment: Is it because English is such a popular language?

Comment: @SovereignSun like it or not English is the primary language of international commerce and diplomacy.  Many countries require students to study it as their main foreign language (although they may choose to study another as an elective), and so you have people all over the world speaking it imperfectly, but nevertheless communicating.

Comment: I love English, really, but I hate it when i can't understand something that I must be able to understand.

Comment: @SovereignSun especially see my #2 comment.  Remember there must be a logic behind every sentence.  Could you post an example of something that you really find frustrating and I can explain how I might try to understand it?

Comment: I've been doing research on short hairstyles and haircuts and found a web site with ridiculous English, http://www.short-haircut.com/really-cool-asymmetrical-pixie-cut-pics.html

Comment: For instance this sentence: Asymmetrical haircut is really nice way to give an unique style to your look no matter **what is your hair length**. (what your hair length is) or Side parted dark short pixie style will **frame** your face and emphasize color of your eyes too! (usage of frame) or This model was one of the trendiest ones used in 2012 year and will remain same way. (is this English at all?)

Comment: @SovereignSun that kind of sounds like the sort of English that regularly crops up in spam email.  All of these seem pretty understandable, except perhaps for "frame" with regard to haircuts, see [this definition of *frame* as a transitive verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frame): "To enclose as if in a (picture) frame"

Comment: @SovereignSun (cc @Andrew) The meaning of your example sentences are quite clear to me. FWIW, I think it's relatively easy to fix them because the meaning is clear. Sure, they're unidiomatic and/or ungrammatical, but they're understandable.

Comment: It's just a tiny bit of what I stumble upon. Sometimes I see really strange use of words or sentences that are unreadable.

Comment: @SovereignSun I know, I've seen some pretty weird and occasionally hilarious stuff.  If you want to post some examples, I can try to decipher them. otherwise, sometimes, you just gotta laugh.  Like one of my favorite "bad" English examples:  (On a sign in a Japanese train station) **"Please do not run into the train"**.  Good advice!

Comment: @Andrew I will bear your offer in mind, my friend .